# Implement HTTPS on Tomcat Server for Pega application

Tags: tomcat, https, ssl-certificate

Q: We have an Tomcat App server and we are running Pega application on top of it, we would like to implement HTTPS for our application. I have been provided with CA certificate to implement HTTPS.

Process:
To achieve this I have created a key store and I have imported the CA certificate into it and changed some configurations in server.xml file. I have also given Key store path and key store password. After restarting the server, I was able to browse the URL with HTTPS, but it is throwing an error saying "this certificate is invalid". As per my understanding, it is taking the key store private key certificate instead of CA certificate which is incorrect. Can some please advise me how to solve this issue.

Comment: is this a valid certificate ? i mean have you generated CSR and uploaded it it on SSL certificate provider to fetch the original certificate ?

Comment: Yes that is a valid certificate and our company has provided that to me. Is there any specific procedure we need to follow to implement https in tomcat ? When we have root certe and env certificate(Issued to complete domain name)

Comment: Check this URL and let me know if it helps. Basically you need to install the root certificate. Once done restart your tomcat server once https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate